# Plesk API - Cannot delete subscription

Tags: plesk

I am trying to use the Plesk API to delete a subscription. We are running version 12.0.18 of Plesk.

The packet sent is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<packet version="1.5.2.0">
<webspace>
    <del>
        <filter>
            <id>{ID}</id>
        </filter>
    </del>
</webspace>
</packet>
```

and the error returned is:

```
Error: Parser error: Request is invalid. Error in line 2: Element 'webspace': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( server, client, domain, subdomain, dns, db_server, mail, migration, certificate, domain_alias ).
```

and the above packet is the example given here: http://plesk.github.io/api-examples/#webspace-del

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify protocol version as version 1.6.6.0
Official Plesk API-RPC documentation is here http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP12/12.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. plesk 12+ specifies API version 1.6.6.0, and in the example for plesk 12 it states:

```cli
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
<webspace>
   <del>
   ...
   </del>
</webspace>
</packet>
```
is the packet version the only thing wrong here?